# How do I test for an aborted function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

What is the correct way to test if a function gets aborted by returning?

```
myFunction (parameter) {
  if (typeof parameter === 'object') return

  // doing any stuff
}
```

**Test (jestJS)**

```
it('myFunction() should return if no valid parameter is passed', () => {
  // SETUP
  wrapper = shallow(<Component />)
  // EXECUTE
  wrapper.instance().myFunction(undefined)
  // VERIFY
  // ??
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to test if a function gets aborted by returning?

The only things you can do are:

1. Have the function return different values depending on the code path, and test the return value. (Your function as shown doesn't have a return value on either path, so the result of calling it is `undefined`, but if `doing any stuff` includes `return something` and `something` is guaranteed not to be `undefined`, you could test for that.)
2. Test for any side-effects the function has.

E.g., unless you provide a means of knowing what happened inside the function, there's no way to tell from outside it.

Comment: wouldn't a spy at least be able to detect that it has been called and that the function returned undefined as expected?

Comment: @Icepickle: Yes -- but both paths in the quoted function return `undefined` (or more accurately: neither path has a return value, so *calling* the function results in `undefined`).

Comment: True, in the current example, it is not showing a return value after the if path either, but that might be an under specification of the op :)

Comment: @Icepickle: Right -- and if so, that's #1 above. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A function will always return - unless it throws an exception (The correct way to abort). If function aborts correctly with an exception, one can assert whether that exception was thrown or not.

If you'd like to test that a method executes to a particular line of code within the method. Assuming you have jasmine on board, you could create a spy on an object within the execution line, and test that spy with assertions.

Otherwise, there is no real way to distinguish between an abort by returning - unless the function is expected to return something and returns nothing.